# What does mean I2C Firmware controlled Master operation, Slave is IDLE

Tags: microcontroller, pic, i2c, microchip

I am trying to learn I2C bus. For learning purpose, I am using `PIC 16F72`. In `PIC 16F72` microchip datasheet, I see if I want to use this microchip as a master it has a mode which is

> I<sup>2</sup>C Firmware controlled Master operation, Slave is IDLE
>   [p. 48 in the [PIC 16F72 datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/39597b.pdf)]

I didn't understand what does mean this.

Comment: You can either configure the PIC as slave (Section 9.3.1) or as master (Section 9.3.2) and you have to select the one or the other.  Section 9.3 is the general description.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To put it into a better perspective, the line in question is a part of the list of I<sup>2</sup>C modes that PIC1672 supports.  Here's the full list:

[image]

*"I<sup>2</sup>C Firmware controlled Master operation"* means that the SSP in this PIC can be configured as an I<sup>2</sup>C bus master.  The contents of the I<sup>2</sup>C transactions in this mode will be defined by firmware (which slave device to talk to and when, what to send, what to receive) .

*"Slave is IDLE"* means that the PIC doesn't act as an I<sup>2</sup>C slave in this mode.